# how to pass parameters in the jQuery .change() function

Tags: jquery, parameters, onchange

I am using the jQuery `.change()` method to execute a function when my dropdown is changed. However when i try to do this i get an error that says

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.ui.dropdownPhase' is null or not an object**

I have tryed using e to help get the control but I was unsuccesful, the dropdownPhase control is being used in a repeater **so it is important for me to know exactly which one was changed.**

Even if i cant pass the exact control I would at least need to know which row.

```
this.ui.dropdownPhase.change(function(e) {
    var x2 = this.ui.dropdownrPhase;                        
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `change()` callback, the `this` is set to the current DOM element. It may not be the same as the `this` you were referring to previously.

To avoid this issue, store a reference to the outer `this` in a variable with another name:

```
var me = this;    
me.ui.dropdownPhase.change(function(e) {
    var x2 = me.ui.dropdownPhase;
});
```